# How to display <td> value based on <th> value

Tags: html, angular

I have three arrays which I have to display in the table. The three arrays are as follows:

```js
let array1 = [
{id: 'p1', name: 'Adam', age: 27},
{id: 'p2', name: 'Jack', age: 20}
{id: 'p3', name: 'Jane', age: 21}
{id: 'p4', name: 'Rock', age: 23}
];

let array2 = [
{id: 'p3', occupation: 'Teacher', marital_status: 'Married'},
{id: 'p4', career: 'Wrestler', hobby: 'Gymming'}
];

let headers = [
  {index: 1, name: 'id'},
  {index: 2, name: 'name'},
  {index: 3, name: 'age'},
  {index: 4, name: 'occupation'},
  {index: 5, name: 'marital_status'},
  {index: 6, name: 'career'},
  {index: 7, name: 'hobby'},
];
```

Now I want to display it inside the table. Here's what I've tried so far.

```html
<table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th *ngFor="let head of headers">{{head?.name}}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let person of array1; index as i">
                    <td>{{ person?.name ? person?.name : '-' }}</td>
                    <td>{{ person?.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ person?.age }}</td>
                    <ng-container *ngFor="let header of headers">
                        <td *ngFor="let item of array2">
                            <ng-container *ngIf="header.name == item[header.name]">{{ item[header.name]}}</ng-container>
                        </td>
                    </ng-container>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I want to display the data based on table header's (th) value

Comment: Firstly, `item.value` doesn't exist on `array2` elements, so `<td *ngFor="let item of array2"><ng-container *ngIf="header.name == item[header.name]">{{ item.value }}</ng-container></td>` wont work. Are there any errors in particular that are getting thrown?

Comment: @PaulThorsen unfortunately no, I have edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for a result like the one in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dypndn?file=src/main.ts). You needed to connect the ids between your arrays. The solution in this stackblitz is *not* a good one, however. You shouldn't put methods in your template as they will run an excessive amount due to change detection. I only created it this way to provide an example solution.

What I would recommend is combining `array1` and `array2` so that all of your elements have the extra fields in one object, instead of referencing two objects that share the same id. This is the simplest and most efficient solution. Alternatively, you could create a pipe that produces the correct result instead of using a method within the template.

Comment: Everything's fine but the labels are dynamic it could be anything.

Comment: I see - that is a detail that would be helpful to add to your question next time. I updated the stackblitz. Be aware that the same issues I described in my answer should be taken into account.

Comment: I get Uncaught Error: Angular JIT compilation failed: '@angular/compiler' not loaded!

Comment: In the stackblitz or on your local machine?

Comment: It kinda works I did some modifications but thank you

Answer (score 0):

create an unique array

```
//first create an objct with all the elements
const emptyObj=headers.reduce(a:any,b:any)=>({...a,b.name:''))

//then create an object using spread operator
arrayFull=this.array1.map(x=>{
   const el=this.array2.find(y=>y.id==x.id)
   return {...emptyObj,...x,...el}
})
```